# Adding JS code snippets (full story, mixpanel, etc.) to Docusaurus.io

Tags: javascript, web, analytics, mixpanel, docusaurus

I'm trying to find out how can I add JS code snippets to work with Docusaurus.io (https://docusaurus.io). I want to add some analytics tools to my Docusaurus based web documentation such as - mixpanel, full story, etc. but I didn't find how can I do it.

Comment: Please, add more details to the question. What did you try so far? Is there some kind of API?

Comment: did you manage to do it ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure exactly where you'd like to put JS snippet in. Here are some scenarios in Docusaurus.

You may add JS file to siteConfig.js, this section:

```
scripts: ['https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js'],
```

If you'd like to add JS snippet to pages, then it is doable since each page is just a React component. Something like this in your render method:

```
<script type="text/javascript" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: js_snippet}} />
```

If you'd like to add JS snippet to docs I think it is pretty hard because docs are in markdown which I don't think you can add script tag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to add Intercom to my Docusaurus site so I need to have a JS snippet. Tried both methods without a success. Do you have any idea why it's not working for me?

Answer (score -1):

Add a `scripts` key into `siteConfig.js` which takes in an array of script sources you want to load in the head. As mentioned on this page - https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/site-config.html#optional-fields

> scripts - Array of JavaScript sources to load. The script tag will be inserted in the HTML head.

So you can add it as such in `siteConfig.js`:

```
const siteConfig = {
  ...
  scripts: [
    'https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js',
    ...
  ],
  ...
};
```